# Switch back and forth between UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have two storyboards with each having different UINavigationControllers. I want each navigation to look different hence having more than one.

`AStoryBoard
ANavigationController --(RootViewController)--> AViewController -> ...OtherViewControllers`

`BStoryBoard
BNavigationController --(RootViewController)--> BViewController`

I would like to jump from `AViewController` to `BViewController` and back to `AViewController` with a back button.

When i user a segue from `AViewController` to `BStoryBoard`, `BViewController` appears on `ANavigationController`. But i want to use `BNavigationController`. SO here is my approach

```
 func goToBFlow() {
    // Get storyboard
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "BStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

This works as expected, but i can't go back. Is this the right approach?

Comment: If you have switched out the navigation controller, you can't go "back".  You could save the previous view controller hierarchy and reinstall the root view controller to go back. It may be simpler to present your B navigationcontroller modally on top of the A navigation controlller.  Then you can dismiss it to get back

Comment: That does make sense. Is there another way to accomplish my goal? Without explicitly saving the entire previous navigation controller

Comment: You don't need to "save" much; simply hold a strong reference to the previous `rootViewController`.  You could present B modally as I suggested